# How to align an element applying css margins that does not get modified according to browsers and screen resolutions?

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

I need some stuff that´s inside a specific div element, to float in a specific place.
Naturally, I get different positions according to screen resolutions and browsers.
I need this block of content to appear on the top right corner, but not at the very very top, but about 3 centimeters from the top.

How can I get the position fixed?

I´ve tried this:

```
#sidebars {
    margin: -37% 1% 0 0;
    width: 35%;
}
```

And it works in one page with a specific browser only (I´m using latest firefox version to test this).

So, I´ve tried a fixed position, only to get a result that does not respect the margins. So, I´ve added some float to the right, with no consequence:

```
#sidebars {
    float: right;
    margin: -37% 1% 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 35%;
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance for your insight!!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you do want a fixed position, but I'm pretty sure you don't need the margins. To be clear, `position: fixed;` will position an element with the window (whereas `absolute` is to the document). I'm betting you're looking for something like this:

```
#sidebars {
    position: fixed;
    width: 35%;
    right:0px;
    top:0px; /* or whatever spacing you said you need from the top of the window */
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Didn´t know that when you set a fixed position, you can set "top" and "right" positions. Terrific! Thanks!!!!